# How do I de-KDE gnome?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, kde, desktop-environments

I was using KDE for a while, but switched back to GNOME. However, some of the styles from KDE got into GNOME, and now I have a weird KDE/GNOME fusion. How do I revert back to GNOME style, and also remove KDE? I am using Debian 11.

Comment: Give some examples. Are you sure you aren't using KDE apps in Gnome?

Comment: @harrymc now that i think about it, the KDE styled apps were installed in KDE, can you help me remove the KDE style? I know how to revert the mouse

Answer (score 0):

KDE apps in Gnome will still look very much the same.

You could uninstall the KDE apps and install their matching Gnome apps.

Comment: reinstalling the apps doesn't work, can you help? If you can't, I can just backup and reinstall debian

Comment: You will need to find Gnome-native apps.